# How can I software disable a display?

Tags: mac, display, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I have a mac mini with two monitors but I often access it remotely over VNC. Screen Sharing (and other vnc clients) allow me to select a single display (or view both at once), but neither work well because if I view a single screen then windows will open on the other one, alerts will pop up, etc. It's also basically impossible to use with both displays shown at once on a 13in laptop screen.

I'm looking for a way to software disable one of the monitors so that I can switch to a single display when I need to.

Comment: I have my monitor connected to a WEMO switch, which I turn on off via a variation of this shell script: http://moderntoil.com/?p=839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution: the open source project [DisableMonitor 3.1](https://github.com/epalzeolithe/DisableMonitor-3.0) let's you easily disable, enable or change the resolution of all monitors attached to your Mac. It supports macOS 10.15 Catalina and Big Sur (Intel) 11.1.

DisableMonitor 3.1 is a fork of the [original project DisableMonitor](https://github.com/Eun/DisableMonitor), which is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you switch between local and remote use frequently enough that disconnecting the second screen is not a viable solution?

One workaround would be to set your secondary display to mirror the main display. This would effectively reduce the 2 monitors to one logical display.

Comment: Correct, remembering to physically disconnect isn't really viable. I've tried mirroring but this causes a weird glitch where the screens will constantly reinitialize several times a second when connected over VNC making it unusable.